# Angular 4 animation transition unexpected behavior

Tags: angular, animation

Using Angular 4.3 and the Angular 4.3 Animations package, it appears that the last transition in a multiple-transition animation doesn't fire. Here is the Plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/F3tHn7?p=preview

In all the demos and courseware I've seen, the div should return to the initial state, but it does not. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div (click)="changeMe = 'active'"
     [@changeState]="changeMe">Click me</div>
```

Component:

```js
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import 'web-animations-js';

import {
    trigger,
    state,
    style,
    animate,
    transition
} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'src/app.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('changeState', [
      state('inactive', style({
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        width: '100px',
        height: '100px'
      })),
      state('active', style({
        backgroundColor: 'magenta',
        width: '100px',
        height: '50px'
      })),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('1000ms')),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('1000ms'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class App {
changeMe = 'inactive';
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This reflects the [Angular.IO documentation](https://angular.io/guide/animations) which says:

```js
animations: [
  trigger('heroState', [
    state('inactive', style({
      backgroundColor: '#eee',
      transform: 'scale(1)'
    })),
    state('active',   style({
      backgroundColor: '#cfd8dc',
      transform: 'scale(1.1)'
    })),
    transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
    transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
  ])
]
```

It's also lifted basically verbatim from well-documented courseware in which I saw it work with Angular 4.0. I checked the release notes and there are not supposed to have been any functionality changes in the 4.3 animations package. I am using @angular/cli. If I'm missing anything, I'd appreciate a pointer, and if there is some change in animations syntax in 4.3 it'd be great if someone could point me to where it's documented.

Thanks for any help...

EDIT: I'm upvoting Vega's answer it made it clear that an Angular-external delay was required to return to the initial state. My misunderstanding was in thinking Angular transitions are executed sequentially. Here is the updated Plunker with the working example straight from the courseware in question. I misunderstood the thing, my bad.

https://plnkr.co/edit/kkTccN?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changMe value is stuck to 'active' value after a click. Change it like this:

```
<div (click)="change()"
 [@changeState]="changeMe">Click me</div>
```

and

```
change(){

  setTimeout(()=>{    
     this.changeMe = this.changeMe== 'active' ? 'inactive' : 'active'
  },1000);
  setTimeout(()=>{    
     this.changeMe = this.changeMe== 'active' ? 'inactive' : 'active'
  },3000);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I would've been really happy if that had worked...but no cigar. See the updated Plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/F3tHn7?p=preview

Comment: Yes, but without the second click. The animation transitions should run consecutively without any further input until the final transition is complete. In the Plunker, it still runs the first transition and then stops without proceeding to the next one until you click again. Maybe I missed something...but it runs exactly like I'm describing it in the courseware I'm looking at right now :-(

Comment: No -- infinite animations aren't supported in Angular, according to the courseware I'm doing. I just want it to execute both the transitions in the array and then stop, not call it quits after the first one. The courseware instructor was able to recreate the issue and confirmed that something's not right here...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151803/discussion-between-vanalbert-and-vega).

Comment: @VanAlbert, I agree that it looks like a hack. The subject is interesting, so I will spend some more time to see how it can be fixed